# Send variables to the Flask frontend using Blueprints

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm working with the following Flask template by AppSeed:

https://github.com/app-generator/flask-datta-able

Currently most of the data is hardcoded in JavaScript scripts. I'm trying to figure out how to send the variables from the Python backend to the frontend (e.g. HTML). My attempts till now were not successful, the variable in the frontend remains empty.

My code looks as follows:

I extended routes.py by:

```
@blueprint.route('/chart-morris')
@login_required
def chart_morris():
    data = '1111'

    return render_template('home/chart-morris.html', data=data)
```

chart-morris.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FlaskBlog</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>{{ data }}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Project's structure:

```
< PROJECT ROOT >
   |
   |-- apps/
   |    |
   |    |-- home/                           # A simple app that serve HTML files
   |    |    |-- routes.py                  # Define app routes
   |    |
   |    |-- static/
   |    |    |-- <css, JS, images>          # CSS files, Javascripts files
   |    |
   |    |-- templates/                      # Templates used to render pages
   |    |    |-- includes/                  # HTML chunks and components
   |    |    |    |-- ...       
   |    |    |
   |    |    |-- layouts/                   # Master pages
   |    |    |    |-- base-fullscreen.html  # Used by Authentication pages
   |    |    |    |-- base.html             # Used by common pages
   |    |    |
   |    |    |-- home/                      # UI Kit Pages
   |    |         |-- index.html            # Index page
   |    |         |-- chart-morris.html     
   |    |    
   |  config.py                             # Set up the app
   |    __init__.py                         # Initialize the app
   |
   |-- .env                                 # Inject Configuration via Environment
   |-- run.py                               # Start the app - WSGI gateway
   |
```